# Add children to user control with ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel

**Question:** How exactly do I add new children to my user control? Ive been told the viewmodel shouldnt know anything about the view and instead work with bindings. Now ive create an items control and set the path of my binding to a property MyLabels which contains and array of Labels. It doesnt work and honestly im not sure what the recommended way is to make it work.

The itemscontrol of my XAML (which is somewhere inside my user control):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Main"
             x:Name="this"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000">

        <ScrollViewer Height="400" Width="900">
            <StackPanel Width="900">
                <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabels}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Image PreviewMouseDown="AddLabel""/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my view model:

```
namespace Test {
    public partial class Main {
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyLabels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public Main() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public void AddLabel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                MyLabels.Add("eee");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check adding some text to the labels if they are adding or not?

Comment: Yes I did. It didnt work

Comment: Also why do you need to inherit `Main` from `UserControl`? I think you can remove that inheritance, events (since no one going to raise your event) and instead keep the VM as pure POCO.

Comment: @SivaGopal thanks, changed it.

Comment: @jαsοndιnAlt I could set an x:Name and just add children directly but that is not good practice. The role of this vm is to bind data to the user control and also add new elements if the user clicks on a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of your view model:

```
public Main() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

The view model is however supposed to be a class of its own:

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

And it shouldn't create any `Label` elements but `strings`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> MyLabels { get; set; } new List<string>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        AddLabels();
    }

    public void AddLabels()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MyLabels.Add("Sample");
        }
    }
}
```

`Label` is a user interface element type and these belong to the view only.

Also note that you can only bind to public *properties*.

> It works now, only problem is im not sure how to add actual labels without violating the MVVM pattern.

You add the `Label` elements in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`. This template defines the appearance of an item in the source collection, i.e. a `string` in this case:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: interesting, ill check it out

Comment: Weird it doesnt work. AddLabels is still an event handler though. Clicking it does nothing in the view. I should see the changes reflecting to the xaml

Comment: Change the type of the collection from List<string> to ObservableCollection<string>. And make sure that it is a property.

Comment: Weird, I got the ItemsControl inside a grid of mine. That grid is inside a user control. Now somehow after changing the datatype to ObservableCollection it still doesnt work

Comment: What's the DataContext of the ItemsControl? Please provide a *full* sample of your issue that can be *easily* reproduced: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updated my question so you can see the entire thing.

Comment: Main is still a view and you are stil not setting the DataContext...?

Comment: Check the first code snipper of my answer; DataContext = this;

Comment: Updated , forgot to add it.

Comment: Are you sure that the AddLabel method is called? Your "button" looks strange so this is probably not your actual code. Use a simple Button for testing purposes.

Comment: It works now, only problem is im not sure how to add actual labels without violating the MVVM pattern.

Comment: You should use the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

With following MVVM mimic(light weight flavor!), you should able to see the labels created in the View. Based on your update, still following generate strings.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyStrings { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddStringCommand { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            if (MyStrings == null) MyStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                MyStrings.Add("string " + i);
            }

            AddStringCommand = new AddLabelCommand(AddString);

        }

        public void AddString()
        {
            MyStrings.Add("string " + (MyStrings.Count));
        }

 }

public class AddLabelCommand : ICommand
{
        readonly Action _action = null;

        public AddLabelCommand(Action commandToExecute)
        {
            _action = commandToExecute; //Handle null condition
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs (Code behind of your view)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml (Inside View)**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="402" Width="540"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/> <!--Initialize ViewModel inside XAML-->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="367" Width="526" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStrings}" Width="100" BorderBrush="Red">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> <!--If you want to display your content in a control you can use ItemTemplate as suggested by @mm8-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Add Label" Height="23" Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=AddStringCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this provide you a starting point!!

Comment: MyLabels will always be null in the constructor of the view model...and a view model class shouldn't create Label element. This violates the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I dont really understand why we need to add the ViewModel to the datacontext inside the view.

Comment: That is one of the ways you tell view where to look for its data. You can do this in view as well.

Comment: Ok it works but in the end im adding text not labels? Not sure where to do this if it violates the MVVM pattern

Comment: It depends. For example if there is a requirement to fetch controls from database and display to View, in that case still you need to fill your ViewModel with those controls collection, isn't it?